# Persistent library search path in Linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I want to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable globally, to use some strange third-party SDK, which places its shared libraries to custom directories. So, I added such script to /etc/profile.d:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ebus_sdk/lib/genicam/bin/Linux64_x64:/usr/local/ebus_sdk/lib/qt/lib:/usr/local/ebus_sdk/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After reboot, I type this in the command line:

```
alex@alex-64:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
.
```

So, this way doesn't work. Is there any other way to add these directories to the library search path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the two lines on one:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ebus_sdk/lib/genicam/bin/Linux64_x64:/usr/local/ebus_sdk/lib/qt/lib:/usr/local/ebus_sdk/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

*Edit*:
Check whether some of the profile files do not overwrite `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Typical candidates are `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` (or appropriate for your kind of shell).

Comment: Yes, bashrc overrides LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Now I think that it is not a good idea to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and trying /etc/ld.so.conf modification (for now, without success). Anyway, original question is answered, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Most linux distros would have you add a file to the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory which contains the path to search for the libraries.  This is a convenient way for installers like `rpm` and `dpkg` to install and uninstall a package's system changes.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did finally. My problem was that it started to work only after executing lgconfig.

Comment: @AlexF: It's `ldconfig`, not lgconfig. Thanks for the tip!